# How to add attributes from polygon layer to point layer when layers have different projections

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, saga

**I have two layers in different coordinate systems:**

- polygon layer with catchment areas and names of the catchments (EPSG 21781)
- point layer with coordinates and flood flows (EPSG 2056)

They of course overlay nicely in QGIS because I have set their CRS correctly.

**Goal:**
Add the attribute "catchment name" to the point layer

**What I have tried so far:**

- **Join attributes by location** is no option because it is a large dataset and crashed when I tried it.
- I have tried to use **SAGA Add attribute to point** but it needs both layers in the same CRS and fails to add the attributes to the point layer.

Is there another tool to add attributes from polygon to point layer?
I am using QGIS 2.14.6 on Win7

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the projection of one of them to be similar to the other. Without having same projections for both shapefile, you cannot do `spatial join` or `join by location` or a`dd attribute to points`. You are seeing them overlaying each other nicely, but in reality they are in different locations because they have different projections.

Comment: I tried setting the same CRS for both layers, so they apparently do not overlay. Running 'add attribute to points' works no without showing the "Unmatching CRS's" notification and the resulting layer has a new column "catchment name" but it is empty, just showing _NULL_.  Do I need to transform one of the layers first?

Comment: Are you turning on the on fly projection? If so turn it off. Then create a new QGIS project and load both files. If they're in the same projection they should overlay each other. Then try again add attribute to point tool.

Comment: On the fly projection is turned off but the two layers are in different projections. How do I get them in the same projection AND overlay each other?

Comment: Right-click on one of the two layers->Save as->choose the output file type (shapefile) -> Write the output file name -> below output file name, there is a place to select the desired output CRS,  select a CRS that matches the other layer, and click OK. The output should have the same CRS of the other layer now.